# Android: How to get file extension with multiple dots in filename?

Tags: file-extension

How can I get a file extension which has more than one dot in the name?

For example:

image.fromyesterday.hello.jpg

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
String something = "image.fromyesterday.hello.jpg"; 
String extension = something.substring(something.lastIndexOf("."));
```

Comment: `something.lastIndexOf(".") + 1` if you wish to get rid of the dot

Comment: Thanks! lastIndexOf takes the last part of the string that matches in this case the dot. :))

Comment: This only works if 'something' always has a '.', otherwise it throws an exception.  You should check if lastIndexOf() != -1.

Answer (score 3):

I think this would be better:

```
String suffixOf(String name){
    if(name == null || name.equals("")){
        return "";
    }
    String suffix = "";
    int index = name.lastIndexOf(".");
    if (index != -1 ) {
        suffix = name.substring(index + 1);
    }
    return suffix;
}
```